# how include links from main urls.py file to model urls.py file?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to include links from a 'Post/urls.py' file, to 'blog/urls.py' (admin file)  but I get an error message
Do you hope to help solve this problem?

#Post/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$',views.all_posts, name='all_posts'),
        url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)$',views.post, name='post'),
    ]
```

blog/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('Post.urls', namespace ='blog')),
]
```

Error msg:
from django.conf.urls import url
ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls' (C:\xampp\htdocs\django\blog\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls_*init*_.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> django.conf.urls.url() was deprecated in Django 3.0, and is removed in
> Django 4.0+.

use `path` instead

#Post/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('',views.all_posts, name='all_posts'),
        path('<id>',views.post, name='post'),
    ]
```